# Calculate double with add 0.1 gives lot of nummers behind the point

Tags: string, flutter, double, overflow

I have a problem with calculate with Double in Flutter.

This is my code:

double depth = 0.5;

```
                        RoundIconButton(
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              depth = depth + 0.1;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

The Outcome comes in a textfield

```
                    Text(
                      depth.toString(),
                      style: kBigTextstyle,
                    ),
```

When I push the plus button, it shows:

0.6

then 0.7

en then 079999999999999

But is has to be 0.8

```
                              depth = depth + 0.10000;
```

double depth = 0.5;

```
                        RoundIconButton(
                          icon: FontAwesomeIcons.plus,
                          onPressed: () {
                            setState(() {
                              depth = depth + 0.1;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
```

The Outcome comes in a textfield

```
                    Text(
                      depth.toString(),
                      style: kBigTextstyle,
                    ),
```

I expect the output of 0.7 + 0.1 to be 0.8 but the actual output is 0.7999999

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of writing

> depth.toString()

please write

`depth.toStringAsFixed(1)`